# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ without any path

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

2 days ago, I created a project, now I am trying to reopen and build it again, but android studio shows such an error, I can't find the solution. The main problem is that there is no path in the error, and it says that error is at 1:1. Can anyone help?

![Look at] https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuaVb.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuaVb.png

Comment: Click the other items in the Build Output window to get a full log

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `AndroidManifest.xml` in your app module.
It probably contains a character somewhere, which makes the Manifest invalid.

I have this sometimes, when I try to save, but accidentally type an "s" instead. E.g look for mistakes like this:

```
s<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
```

Note, the extra 's'

Comment: https://files.fm/u/tsweg64xq
I can't find any:(